# Can we use amqp://user:password@ instead of amqp://user:password@localhost for local connections?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmq-shovel

Can we use that shortened syntax?
I've been suggested that usage of such short amqp url forces rabbitmq to work in "direct" mode, which is more efficient.
However, when I changed my local connections settings for shovels like that, I don't see those connections in connections list anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel-static.html

Specifically:

> If the host is omitted (not valid in a general AMQP URI), the shovel
>   uses a direct connection to the broker in which it is running. This
>   avoids using the network stack